# What is a good working fluid in the temperature range of 150 - 180 °F?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid

I am looking for a good working fluid whose boiling point is in the range of 150 - 180 °F for a waste heat recovery system. The fluid should be minimally flammable, preferably nontoxic, and low in environmental impact. Does anyone know of any working fluids that match this description?

Comment: Many sources give those details about fluids: density, viscosity, temperatutre etc

Comment: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/boiling-points-fluids-gases-d_155.html, but I doubt the organic liquids you are going to get are very friendly to dea with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use water. It is cheap, plentiful, nontoxic and plentiful- plus it has an very high specific heat. All of these things make it ideal for heat transfer purposes. Just choose the *system operating pressure* to be enough *below* ambient to depress the boiling point to the range you desire.

Comment: Are lower pressure steam Rankine cycles often used?

Comment: @HypnosStratagem, I do not know, but subatmospheric water refrigeration has been in use for over 100 years. it is called *steam refrigeration* and the process lends its name to a old brand of beer called *Anchor Steam Beer* which used steam refrigeration to control temperatures during the fermentation process 120 years ago.